# PHP Redirects based on type of client - email, http etc

Tags: php, .htaccess, email, redirect, conditional-statements

I am kind of new to `PHP` and I am just wondering if there is a way to `REDIRECT` a `URL` **based on the type of client that the call has come from**? Like if a user is clicking a link in a email client as opposed to a `HTTP` request.

Is there a difference? Can it be done?

---

**So for example:**

```
IF "http://somesite.com/somesubpage.php"  

do THIS  

ELSE if "EMAIL CLIENT"  

do SOMETHING ELSE
```

---

Hope someone can answer this. It could be in `PHP` or in `htaccess`.

Comment: This is the most basic thing to do in PHP. If you don't know how this is done, then learn the basics first before asking a question here

Answer (score 2):

If a user clicks on a link in an e-mail, and the link opens in a web browser, this is still considered an HTTP request.

If you want to track clicks on links within an e-mail, one common solution is to add a query string to the link.  For example, your homepage might be:

`http://www.example.com/index.php`

But from your e-mail, you can link to:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?source=email`

and then track the source variable from within the index.php script.